# Git Checkout branch merge old files

Tags: git, git-branch, git-merge

I have a branch name `test1` and I make a new branch named as `test2` by following command. Currently my branch is `test1` I run this command

```
$ git checkout -b test2
```

It creates the new branch and work on that `test2` branch. After completing my my task on `test2` branch I switch back to my original branch `test1` but it also merge the changing of `test2` branch that is not good. Because I want to separate the logic of both branches. Now my original branch also become unstable.
I just want to know that why `test2` code merge in my `test1` branch when I checkout?

Comment: This shouldn't happen. Post the whole commands please.

Comment: @MarounMaroun I just run first command then work on new branch then simple checkout test1 branch.

Comment: Unless explicitly added files in git aren't under a version control. Am I correct to assume that a file created during test2 being active is still around when switching to another branch?

Answer (score 2):

Uncomitted changes don't belong to any specific branch, that's why they will just stay in the working directory. When those changes would conflict with changes from the other branch, `git checkout` will abort and say so.

You have to commit your changes on branch *test2*. After this, when you checkout *test1*, those changes will disappear.

Note that people are often reluctant of committing changes because they're not yet finished with their work. In git, it's hardly a problem, because it's easy enough to amend the last commit, or undo it with `git reset HEAD^` and recommit with the latest changes.

Answer (score 1):

I think that you did merge test2 to test1.

Whatever, you can use git commands as follow to clear your test1 branch.

```
git log               # copy the latest commit id before commits you committed on test2
git reset <commit id> # reset to that commit 
git checkout .        #  checkout the modifies you merged into test1 from test2
```

now the branch test1 is clear